# pystan Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807

Tags: python, cython, spyder, facebook-prophet, pystan

I am having a trouble when I want to install fbprophet.It say's that I need to install cython and pystan first.Cython is already installed but I have an error regarding pystan;

- note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pystan
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for pystan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807*

Any solution about this please?